# Lucene .Net, do i need to close IndexWriter

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

We are having locking issues with `Lucene .Net` throwing a `LockObtainFailedException`. It is a multi tenanted site and each customer gets their own physical search index on disc, and a `static` list of `IndexWriters` is used, one per index to control changes.

We call the following functions on the `IndexWriter`

```
AddDocument();
DeleteDocuments();
DeleteAll();
Optimize();
Commit();
```

I have noticed that we never call `Close()` or `Dispose()` on the `IndexWriter`, and wanted to know if this was good practice and could be the cause of the issues.

Thanks Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say yes, but only when you're killing off the application itself - otherwise, no. Here's the docs for IndexWriter.Dispose in Lucene.Net 4.8:

> Commits all changes to an index, waits for pending merges to complete,
>   and closes all associated files.
>
> This is a "slow graceful shutdown" which may take a long time ...
>
> Note that this may be a costly operation, so, try to re-use a single
>   writer instead of closing and opening a new one.  See `Commit()` for
>   caveats about write caching done by some IO devices.

https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Index/IndexWriter.cs#L996

So, you should call `.Dispose()`, but, typically only once when you're shutting down the app. [It is not however clear whether you need to Dispose() its underlying objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341781/do-i-need-to-call-dispose-on-the-standardanalyzer-or-does-dispose-on-the)

You're already calling `.Commit()`, which they recommend instead. I would guess your problem is actually related to threading. I'm just learning Lucene, but if I were in your position I'd try putting a standard .Net lock around any write calls to Lucene, so that only one thread has access to writes at a time. If it solves your issue, you know it was threading.

Locks are awfully painful, and Lucene writes may take a long time, so if the lock solves this issue it may introduce other problems like 2 threads attempting to write and one hanging or failing depending on how your code is written. If that does arise you'd probably want to implement a Write Queue so threads can quickly hand off what they'd like written to a cheap data structure like ConcurrentQueue, and then have those write ops startup the write operation if none is running, and keep dequeuing until everything's written out - then back to sleep.

Answer (score -1):

To use Close/Dispose when you don't need the object any longer is always a good idea. There is a reason why a developer exposes these methods. Typically, the documentation give additional hints when to use these methods.

I also advise to use every `IDisposeable`-object in a `using`-block, which just calls `Dispose()`.

This gives objects the ability to clean up and free resources. In case of framework-objects this isn't really important since the garbage collector will care sooner or later, but in case of system-objects or handles like file-system handles `Dispose` becomes important. These handles might stay open.

In the case of the Lucene IndexWriter I'm not perfectly sure, but when it uses a file for its index (which is what I assume), then you have a reason why `Dispose` should be called.

When handles/connections/etc stay open it can lead to such exceptions. So, yes, you should use `Close()`/`Dispose()`

Comment: Thanks, I understand IDisposable and the Dispose pattern, I was looking for an answer specific to Lucene.