# Do I need to call .Dispose() on the StandardAnalyzer, or does .Dispose() on the IndexWriter dispose its descendants?

Tags: lucene.net, dispose, idisposable

Initializing an IndexWriter in Lucene.Net looks like this:

```
var analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(version);
var indexWriterConfig = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriterConfig(version, analyzer);
Index = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter(luceneDir, indexWriterConfig);
```

That is, you can't instantiate an IndexWriter without an Analyzer. So, I would expect that calling `.Dispose()` on the IndexWriter would dispose its children, including the Analyzer. However browsing the code I don't see that happening - so far. Have I missed it?

So: Does calling `.Dispose()` on the IndexWriter dispose the Analyzer, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IndexWriter does not dispose of the analyzer.

It doesn't dispose of the analyzer because it cannot be sure that you will not be using the analyzer elsewhere. It's a reference that it got via the constructor, it could be used by other IndexWriter instances without it knowing.

It's about ownership; you created the analyzer and let the writer use it. It is thus your responsibility to dispose of the analyzer.

Comment: I confirmed that this answer is correct by reviewing the source code at https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Index/IndexWriter.cs